# Define JavaScript array literal with conditional elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a JavaScript array using a literal containing the elements.  I only want a chunk of those elements (somewhere in the middle of the array) to be included if a certain expression is true.  I can obviously create the array with the always-present elements only then programmatically insert the additional elements at the appropriate index if the condition is true, but I don't want to do that because the non-ES6 ways of doing it are not very pretty and you have to mentally think about indexes to understand where the conditional elements are going to go if the condition is true (not very readable).  Here is a simplified example of what I know how to do (but dislike) versus what I'd like to do (but don't know how).  In the last example, instead of `undefined` at the index, I simply don't want an element there.  Is there a way to achieve this with a literal and expressions, or will I have to end up doing some array manipulation to achieve this?

```js
function createArrayTheWayIDislike(condition) {
    var array = [
        'a',
        'd'
    ];
    if(condition) {
       array.splice.apply(array, [1, 0].concat(['b', 'c']));
    }
    console.log(array);
}

function createArrayTheWayIWantTo(condition) {
    var array = [
        'a',
        condition ? 'b' : undefined,
        condition ? 'c' : undefined,
        'd'
    ];
    console.log(array);
}

createArrayTheWayIDislike(true);
createArrayTheWayIDislike(false);

createArrayTheWayIWantTo(true);
createArrayTheWayIWantTo(false);
```

Comment: the rest operator doesn't work well?, for example if you want to insert starting at arr[1], arr[3] = ..myArr

Comment: @afcosta Still would be dealing with indexes more than I prefer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can filter the results before returning the array

```js
function createArrayTheWayIWantTo(condition) {
    var array = [
        'a',
        condition ? 'b' : undefined,
        condition ? 'c' : undefined,
        'd'
    ].filter(e => e);
    
    console.log(array);
}

createArrayTheWayIWantTo(true);
createArrayTheWayIWantTo(false);
```

Comment: So just filtering out the `undefined` elements after defining the array.  Pretty much what I want while maintaining readability.

Comment: You may want to use `e => e !== undefined` for the filter, depending on what your array contains. Using the identity function will remove all falsy elements from the array.

Answer (score 1):

How about using array destructuring, with a ternary operator to do this? Here's an example:

```js
// Replace with your real conditions
const condition1 = true;
const condition2 = false; 

const array = [
  'a',
  ...condition1
    ? ['b']
    : [],
  ...condition2
    ? ['c']
    : [],
  'd'
];

// Should log ['a', 'b', 'd'];
console.log(array);
```

Comment: While this works and I appreciate the answer, I am trying to avoid ES6 features like destructuring in my app (for browser compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use this syntax which I quite like:

```js
const arr = Array.skipUndef(
 'a',
 condition ? 'b' : undefined,
 condition ? 'c' : undefined,
 'd'
)
```

Under the hood it's the same as `[...].filter((arg) => arg)` but with some minor syntactic sugar (I personally don't like the option with the `filter` line, especially when the array is long and you have multiple levels of indent and it's just kind of dangling there somewhere at the end).

In order to do this, just write the following file somewhere and import it into your `index.ts`:

```js
declare global {
  interface ArrayConstructor {
    skipUndef<T>(...args: (T | undefined)[]): T[];
  }
}

Array.skipUndef = function <T>(...args: (T | undefined)[]) {
  return args.filter((arg) => arg !== undefined) as T[];
};
```